# Client Side Filtering vs Server Side Filtering

Tags: java, java-ee

Хотел узнать о задачи каждого из типов фильтрации..

1. Что именно фильтруется на клиентской стороне ?
2. Что именно фильтруется на стороне сервера ?
3. Какова может быть цель фильтрации клинентской стороны ?
4. Какова может быть цель фильтрации серверной стороны ?

Если кто сможет предоставить ссылки на примеры кода для понимания 1-4, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виды и назначения фильтрации зависят от разновидности клиентов/серверов, но раз речь про JEE то буду исходить из того, что клиент это браузер а сервер bean обслуживающий страницу facelet.

> "Что именно фильтруется на клиентской стороне ?"

Все что можно отфильтровать. Фильтрация может полностью совпадать с серверной. Данная проверка это так называемая "защита от дурака", целью которой является помочь пользователю правильно "оформить" запрос.

> "Что именно фильтруется на стороне сервера ?"

Нужно фильтровать все т.к. серверная фильтрация это проверка на то что в алгоритм попадут данные в правильном формате и в первую очередь что данные от пользователя не могут нанести вред серверу или привести к несанкционированному доступу и любым другим проблемам безопасности.

> "Какова может быть цель фильтрации клиентской стороны ?"

В первую очередь уменьшение нагрузки на сервер (http трафик, обработка запроса и т.п.). Из второстепенных причин можно назвать ускорение валидации - к примеру ненужно отправлять форму и ждать ответа.

> "Какова может быть цель фильтрации серверной стороны ?"

Гарантия, что ошибка получения неверных данных будет выявлена максимально быстро (а не в середине процесса вычислений), и что данные не скомпрометируют безопасность сервера.

[Ссылка на то что и как валидировать(материал на английском).](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)

Comment: Отличный ответ спс! Надо найти на GitHub примеры кода из проектов по такой теме..

Answer (score 0):

Тут очень обширный ответ можно дать. 
Ну во-первых на стороне сервера фильтруется всё связанное с информационной безопасностью (валидный ввод, для защиты от sql запросов, например). Количество обращений к серверу, сомнительные действия и т.д. А так же просто валидируются различные параметры, чтобы система неожиданно не упала, например юзер решил загрузить файл размером в 1000 gb :)
Что фильтруется на клиенте? Ровно тоже самое, что и на сервере, но цель у этого другая. На клиенте мы во-первых, подсказываем юзеру, где он мог ошибиться, а во-вторых не отправляем лишние (бракованные) запросы на сервер, чтобы не загружать его лишний раз. Те, в теории, если бы злоумышленников не было и фильтрация на стороне клиента всегда бы работала - нам бы хватило и её.